# Can you extract both year AND month from date in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot

I have a dataframe with a date column (type datetime). I can easily extract the year or the month to perform groupings, but I can't find a way to extract both year and month at the same time from a date. I need to analyze performance of a product over a 1 year period and make a graph with how it performed each month. Naturally I can't just group by month because it will add the same months for 2 different years, and grouping by year doesn't produce my desired results because I need to look at performance monthly.

I've been looking at several solutions, but none of them have worked so far.

So basically, my current dates look like this

```
2018-07-20
2018-08-20
2018-08-21
2018-10-11
2019-07-20
2019-08-21
```

And I'd just like to have `2018-07, 2018-08, 2018-10`, and so on.

Comment: Is the date an index?

Comment: Check out [`to_period`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html)

Comment: Just as an alternative, since you can extract `year` and `month` individually, you can go `groupby(['year', 'month'])`. It gives you more latitude when it comes to visualizations.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `to_period`

```py
df['month_year'] = df['date'].dt.to_period('M')
```

Comment: But again, wouldn't this give me a grouping where the results of repeated months are consolidated into one? My analysis runs from July 2018 to September 2019

Comment: You would perform your group by after this. You need to specify what it means to consolidate into one. eg: mean/sum/count etc.

Comment: @Dasphillipbrau this is recommended and fits your need.

Answer (score 6):

If they are stored as datetime you should be able to create a string with just the year and month to group by using datetime.strftime (https://strftime.org/).

It would look something like:

```
df['ym-date'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
```

Comment: This code snippet will not work, it will throw an AttributeError, you need to do:

`df['ym-date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m')`

Answer (score 2):

If you have some data that uses datetime values, like this:

```
sale_date = [
    pd.date_range('2017', freq='W', periods=121).to_series().reset_index(drop=True).rename('Sale Date'),
    pd.Series(np.random.normal(1000, 100, 121)).rename('Quantity')
]
sales = pd.concat(data, axis='columns')
```

[image: Sample data]

You can group by year and date simultaneously like this:

```
d = sales['Sale Date']
sales.groupby([d.dt.year.rename('Year'), d.dt.month.rename('Month')]).sum()
```

[image]

You can also create a string that represents the combination of month and year and group by that:

```
ym_id = d.apply("{:%Y-%m}".format).rename('Sale Month')
sales.groupby(ym_id).sum()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A couple of options, one is to map to the first of each month:

Assuming your dates are in a column called 'Date', something like:

`df['Date_no_day'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(day=1))`

If you are really keen on storing the year and month only, you could map to a `(year, month)` tuple, eg:

`df['Date_no_day'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: (x.year, x.month))`

From here, you can groupby/aggregate by this new column and perform your analysis

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to transform the column to get the first of month for all of these dates and then create your analsis on month to month:

```
date_col = pd.to_datetime(['2011-09-30', '2012-02-28'])
new_col = date_col + pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1)
```

Here your analysis remains intact as monthly